# RxSearchView after cleaning with backspace

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-binding

I have RxSearchView:

```
RxSearchView.queryTextChanges(searchView)
            .filter(charSequence -> !TextUtils.isEmpty(charSequence))
            .debounce(600, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(query -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });
```

When I search word `test` the `Toast` shows me `test`, after that I would like to clean searching text using backspace, and the problem is when the search is empty in the `Toast` appears with text `t`.

How to solve this problem ?

I was trying to use `.filter(item -> item.length() > 1)` but this doesn't work too, in that case `Toast` appears with text `te`

[image]

Comment: Can you post a gif/video with that behavior? Judging by your code it should work as expected.

Comment: @azizbekian I have added a gif image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in sequence.
`debounce` must be before `filter`

This will work:

```
RxSearchView.queryTextChanges(searchView)
            .debounce(600, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .filter(charSequence -> !TextUtils.isEmpty(charSequence))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(query -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });
```